# Where can I find the include file in Hadoop-1.2.0 single node cluster on ubuntu?

Tags: hadoop

I am trying set the include file on my Hadoop-1.2.0 single node cluster so that no other nodes can talk to the namenode, other that what are in the include file. Not sure how to go about this

I have set up a single node cluster and am currently new to Hadoop. I have an openssh-server installed and have set up the namenode directory and you can view my [hdfs-site.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3WqT.jpg) here.

Comment: What have you already tried? If you have tried something, please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for code. Copy and paste in the question, please

Comment: Also, if you are just installing Hadoop, why are you using a version that is years old?

Comment: And I'm not sure what you mean by "include file", but it sounds like you need an iptables rule to block out traffic except a few recognized IP addresses

Answer (score 1):

If you have done the setup manually then you have to set the ssh connections to the other hosts, manually. So, if you have not setup the ssh connections then you are good.

For a UI based installation you have if you have not specified the other hosts you want to add to the cluster then there are no other task-nodes/data-nodes that are connecting.

If you are trying to restricts users then you have to look at the ACLs and allow connections to only your subnet. For users unique user-id and password is good enough for the restriction.

Comment: I have manually setup the cluster. I have an openssh-server installed. Where can I find the include file or where is it configured?

Comment: Which include file are you looking for? Most of the Hadoop Jars are in the lib directories of the particular project if you need to use them.